# Radio button not working properly in Angular 2

Tags: angular

We have an angular2 component where we have certain radio buttons. I check the radio buttons on certain conditions.

The HTML code for radio buttons goes as:

```html
<span class="radio-switch-group">
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="radioView" id="All" (click)="onBtnClick('All')" [checked]="currentTab === 'All'">
 <span class="radio-label">ALL Cars</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioView" id="Honda" (click)="onBtnClick('Honda')" [checked]="currentTab === 'Honda'">
        <span class="radio-label">Honda</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

The ts file is as follows:

```
     export class CarComponent implements OnInit{
         @Input() public currentTab: string = 'All';

         public onBtnClick(carType: string){
             this.currentTab = carType;
         }

         public ngOnInit() {
             this.currentTab = 'All';
         }
     }
```

When I instantiate this component in a **tab view** from another component the radio button isnt checked even when the currentTab is set to 'All'

Comment: this code is worked fine for me, please check your code anywhere else the checkbox value is clearing

Comment: I am instantiating this component in a tab, it doesn't work under that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[value]` attribute binding of the input. IIRC using `[selected]` or `[checked]` in Angular is essentially doing the following.

`if ([checked]===[value])`

```html
<span class="radio-switch-group">
    <label>
 <input type="radio" name="radioView" id="All" (click)="onBtnClick('All')" [value]="'All'" [checked]="currentTab">
 <span class="radio-label">ALL Cars</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioView" id="Honda" (click)="onBtnClick('Honda')" [value]="'Honda'"[checked]="currentTab">
        <span class="radio-label">Honda</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Comment: Single quotes inside of the double quotes! Should have realized!

Comment: @Daniel Cooke - What if I want to get the value of checked radio button on template driven form submit ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @Input(), declare just a variable like below:

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit{
     public currentTab: string = 'All';

     public onBtnClick(carType: string){
         this.currentTab = carType;
     }

     public ngOnInit() {
         this.currentTab = 'All';
     }
 }
```

@Input is responsible for one way binding in angular2.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: `@Input` is also two-way -- it depends on how the parent element is using it.